# Rails 2.2.2: Render an template with yield, inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, yield

I'n trying to write out an html file onto our filesystem, so it can be zipped up and sent out, along with some other stuff.

I have an erb template I want to use, in our `app/views/layouts` folder.  That template has a standard `<%= yield %>` call in it, and in this instance I have a bunch of pre-generated html, as a string in my method, that I want to replace yield with.

So, I need to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
string = "<div>This is some <strong>html</strong></div>"
erb_template = "app/views/layouts/my_layout.html.erb"
output_filename = "/tmp/output.html"

#something like this...
render_to_file(erb_template, output_filename) do 
  string
end
```

It might be simpler for me to try to just gsub out `<%= yield %>` and replace it with my text, but that feels like a cop out...

Btw, if it's easier to get the result as a string, eg using `render_to_string`, and then write it to a file myself, that's fine.  It's the evaluation of the template with the yield inside that I don't get...

EDIT:  I've tried changing `<%= yield %>` to `<%= @content %>`, and then doing this, but they both raise a "protected method call" error:

```
c = ActionController::Base.new()
html = c.render_to_string :template => erb_template, :layout => false, :locals => {:content => string}

c = ApplicationController.new()
html = c.render_to_string :template => erb_template, :layout => false, :locals => {:content => string}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths).
  render(template: "your/template", locals: { foo: "bar" })
```

This should successfully render the template at `views/your/template.html.erb`:

```
<h1>My template</h1>
<div>Foo: <%= foo %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this:

I changed the template so that instead of a `<%= yield %>` block, i had

```
<%= @content %>
```

I then called it like this:

```
string = "<div>This is some <strong>html</strong></div>"
erb_template = "app/views/layouts/my_layout.html.erb"
output_filename = "/tmp/output.html"

template = ERB.new(File.read(erb_template))
@content = string     
html = template.result(binding)
File.open(output_filename, "w"){|f| f.puts html}
```

`binding` is the state of the current scope (ie with all the same variables etc), so it uses the @content which I'd just defined.  This probably isn't the cleanest way, and it's not quite what I asked for, but thought I'd leave it here as an answer anyway.  I'm still curious to know if it can be done with the `<%= yield %>` rather than using an instance var (like i have) or a local var (like Máté Solymosi's answer).